# Push notification in mutiple platforms using Amazon SNS API

Tags: java, android, ios, push-notification, amazon-sns

I want to send same messages to multiple platforms(Android and iOS) at the same time.How can i achieve this using Amazon SNS API.Can anyone suggest any useful links?
I need something like below.But i don't konw how to publish this meaasge.Becuase for each platforms  we have different End point ARN.Also i want to know what is the need of topic creation?

```
{ 
"default": "This is the default message which must be present when publishing a message to a topic. The default message will only be used if a message is not present for 
one of the notification platforms.",     
"APNS": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"Check out these awesome deals!\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\"} }",
"GCM":"{\"data\":{\"message\":\"Check out these awesome deals!\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\"}}",
"ADM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Check out these awesome deals!\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\" }}" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-dg.pdf. This contains the info that you require.

Topic is like a specific channel to which users can subscribe and you can publish notifications to. You can create multiple topics and have users subscribe to the topics that they desire in the app. For e.g. in a news app people can subscribe to different news categories and you can send notifications related to a particular news category to that topic ARN. Only people subscribed to that topic will get that notification.